# Looking for a java library to make dynamic moving for JTables (swing)

Tags: java, swing, libraries

I am looking for a way in which i can move JTables within a JPanel. so i can have multiple tables loaded in a panel and be able to drag and drop around a workspace.

any thought would be greatly appricated

Thanks

Comment: Rob has a [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) which might suffice

Answer (score 2):

You can use a MouseInputAdapter:

```
class DragableTable extends JTable {
    public DragableTable(){
        DragDropAdapter adp=new DragDropAdapter(this);
        this.addMouseListener(adp);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(adp);
    }

    class DragDropAdapter extends MouseInputAdapter {
        private DragableTable parent;

        public DragDropAdapter(DragableTable parent){
            this.parent=parent;
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // update location of
            parent.setLocation(e.getPoint());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the `MouseEvent` location is relative to the component that generated, this won't produce desirable results. You've also failed to take into consideration that in order to achieve this, you'll need to disable the layout manager and take control over not only the positioning, but also the sizing of the components

Comment: The code I posted was not meant to be a solution, just the idea. You're right about the layout - I made the assumption that the layout was absolute, since I imagine trying a simple drag and drop would be really difficult for any other layout